# Save animation for Animator

Tags: notebooks, animation, wolfram-cloud

I have a notebook with a dynamic `ParametricPlot` and wanted to save it as an animation, but nothing seems to work. I tried with other local objects (A2) but somehow the "Animator" fails to produce "Animations".

```
zetaFunction[s_, t_] := Zeta[s + I*t];
zrange = 10;
A1 = Animator[Dynamic[dd], {0, 1, .1}] ;
A2 = Dynamic[
  ParametricPlot[
   {Re[zetaFunction[dd,a]], Im[zetaFunction[dd,a]]}, 
   {a, 0, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10,10}, {-10,10}}
  ]
];
Export["trial.mov",A1]
```

What am I missing here? I also tried an approach with `Table` but couldn't get it to work and really seems like the wrong approach here.
Any help/hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try this:

```
animation =
  AnimationVideo[
    ParametricPlot[
      {Re[zetaFunction[dd, a]], Im[zetaFunction[dd, a]]},
      {a, 0, 100},
      PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}],
    {dd, 0, 1, .1}]
```

As for

> What am I missing here?

`Dynamic` is a UI "object". It doesn't hold all of the data needed for the animation/video, so it won't "know" how to export as a video. `Animator` will similarly be unable to "know" what to export. These tools use special dynamic updating functionality, but they aren't in themselves the data structures that they're displaying. So, exporting them is probably problematic or impossible regardless of the type of data they're displaying.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Much appreciated!

Comment: This answer works, as I couldn't get the plot to show using `Animate`.

Comment: This also seems to be the only way to get a nice preview in the notebook.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) instead of `Animator` and `Dynamic`.

```
anim = Animate[
  ParametricPlot[{Re[zetaFunction[dd, a]], 
    Im[zetaFunction[dd, a]]}, {a, 0, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {dd, 0, 1, .1}]

Export["trial.mov", anim]
```

Comment: OMG thanks a ton! I spent hours with Animator, you saved me. I also had to use `CloudObject` bu thats unrelated to the actual animation part.

Comment: Now I just have to find out where there is no graph in the output video :-))